How to solve Google recaptcha using seleniumbase?
I am scraping the following site using seleniumbase.
Before going to the login page, you need to solve cloudfare captcha, which the program solve with no problem, but when you input your login information, before clicking the login button, you have to solve Google recaptcha.
The code I am using is the following:
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(uc=True)
try:
    driver.uc_open_with_reconnect("dashboard.scrape.do/login", 4)

    # Handle cloudfare catpcha
    driver.uc_gui_click_captcha()

    # Fill input fields
    driver.type("#username", "example@gmail.com")
    driver.type("#userpassword", "PASSWORD")

    # Opens the Google recaptcha
    driver.uc_gui_click_captcha()
    # THE LOGIC FOR SOLVING THE GOOGLE CAPTCHA SHOULD BE HERE
    # ....

    driver.sleep(3)
    # Click the login button....

finally:
    driver.quit()

I couldn't find in the seleniumbase documentation how to solve Google recaptcha.
Does anyone know is there a way to solve it using seleniumbase?
